# GraphRequest, executeAsync, Android: Why is there a NullPointerException?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, nullpointerexception

I am using Facebook GraphRequest to get user details and then use those details to store in Firebase and also locally in sharedPreferences. This is the piece of code:-

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

Profile userProfile; /* Profile is a user-created class */

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    facebookLoginButton.registerCallback(facebookCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            String fullName,email;
                            try {
                                 fullName=object.getString("name");
                                 email = object.getString("email");
                                 /* Initializing userProfile */
                                 userProfile=new Profile(fullName,email);
                                 firebaseReference.setValue(userProfile); //This works, which means userProfile is NOT null here
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.d("JSONerror",e.toString());
                            }
                        }
                    });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();

            saveProfileInfoLocally();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {}
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {}
    });

void saveProfileInfoLocally(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("UserInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    editor.putString("fullName",userProfile.getFullName()); //BUT this does NOT work, says userProfile is null
    editor.apply();
}}
```

However, when I try to access the userProfile's details in saveProfileInfoLocally(), it throws a NullPointerException, saying "attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference". Please tell me what is wrong and best way to get it done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you call your saveProfileInfoLocally() outside the **new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback()** which is the callback that actually fetches the profile.

You should move the method call inside the callback as in the following example:

```
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        String fullName,email;
                        try {
                             fullName=object.getString("name");
                             email = object.getString("email");
                             /* Initializing userProfile */
                             userProfile=new Profile(fullName,email);

                             saveProfileInfoLocally();

                             firebaseReference.setValue(userProfile); //This works, which means userProfile is NOT null here
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.d("JSONerror",e.toString());
                        }
                    }
                });

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but what I don't understand is - Why does it say  "userProfile" is null, even though I've initialized it?

Comment: Because you had not initialised it :) 
The code that initialised the profile was INSIDE the callback. And a callback defines something that happens asynchronously. Meaning it can happen now, or in 10 mins from now. But you were calling the saveProfileInfoLocally() method OUTSIDE the callback. So your code was trying to save the Profile object, without knowing if the GraphJSONObjectCallback has completed.

Obviously, the callback was not completed and the Profile was null :)

Comment: I thought of this as a reason, but I'm confused as, this line - firebaseReference.setValue(userProfile) - sets the value and Firebase shows the user data in its database. Which means the userProfile has been created and it's not null. Am I correct?

Comment: No. It's exactly what I am trying to explain. EVERY LINE OF CODE BETWEEN THIS CLAUSE "GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {.. code ... code .... code... }" is executed asynchronously. 
You cannot assume that code inside the clause has finished executing when you are from outside of the clause.

Comment: Thanks. How to know GraphJSONObjectCallback has completed?

Comment: WHEN it completes, the public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) { ...} method is called. So you put in there whatever you want to do AFTER it completes :)

Comment: This is what I'm doing. Thanks anyways :)